# Integrating WebService (JAX-RS) with Java Stripes

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, stripes

I have a web application developed in Stripes. Now I need to develop RESTful webservices (probably using JAX-RS) in the same app. How do I integrate my Stripes application to contain these webservices, is there any sample available, or any other method other than JAX-RS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Stripes is a web application framework (i.e., mainly presentation tier) whereas JAX-RS is a standard for doing RESTful web services (i.e., mainly business logic tier), I'd be strongly tempted to have two separate servlets, one for the Stripes part and one for the JAX-RS part. The Stripes part would then access the JAX-RS part for its back-end.

It is probably possible to deploy both parts in the same container, but I've not a lot of experience with that.

(You'll want to select which JAX-RS implementation you're using fairly early. The ones I know of are Jersey and CXF, and they have enough differences — driven from different sets of use cases — that you won't want to switch between them.)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem now. JAX-WS servlet should work in combination with Stripes servlet and here is the problem.

**web.xml excerpt:**

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>net.sourceforge.stripes.controller.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping> 

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>WebConnectorService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>my.sample.application.WebConnectorService</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebConnectorService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ws</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In this case JAX-WS servlet is working but all the other requests are not processed by Stripes.
Does anybody have any new updates to the issue? Thanks.

UPDATE: I have figured out that requests were processed by both servlets however the problem is because now the application has context root equal to the name of the WAR package. However I have

```
<context-root>/</context-root>
```

in jboss-web.xml and it behaves as expected in case WebConnector servlet is not included. As soon as WebConnector servlet is included in web.xml, the configuration above is ignored.